# Pegar dados do usuário logado - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Preciso pegar os dados do usuário logado, pois algumas telas, apenas os usuários com permissão de administrador terão acesso.

Como faço para guardar os dados da sessão com AngularJS? Estou utilizando Java no backend.

Comment: Faça uma requisição ajax cada vez que entrar nas telas. (não é o melhor modo, mas essa é a resposta p/ sua pergunta)

Comment: Certo, dessa forma funciona sim. Mas como faço da maneira correta?